# number to varchar2 storage query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `number` field with lenght of 10 bytes. If i store this lenght into another field that is of datatype `VarChar2`. How do I calculate the lenght of `VarChar2`?.

Some state that I can just declare it as `VarChar2(MAX)` as it does not matter - saying that if I was to store the word `'999'` into VarChar(100) and VarChar(1000) the same amount of space would be allocated.

What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: A number field with a length of 10 bytes, or 10 digits? What's the exact data type?

Comment: So if you have `1000` as `number`, you need to store its length ie `4` in a `varchar2`?

Comment: That is what i am asking. If i have a number e.g. 1000. What is the lenght if it was a varchar2? Also if it was a double, e.g. 1000.1 I would require a varchar2 with lenght of 6?

Comment: Use `LENGTH(yournumberColumn)`

Comment: if you are saving 1000 as varchar2 then its length would be 4.

Comment: Thank you. And if you store a double, I assume I need to allocate space for the decimal point too?

Comment: If you have column or variable with number(10) it can hold from 0 to 9999999999 so better you can create a column with varchar2(10) it will hold ten characters.

Comment: You may want to read here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858562/why-using-anything-else-but-varchar24000-to-store-strings-in-an-oracle-databas  it has some useful supporting info ...

Comment: A "double" is an internal representation of a number. What you are asking about is storing a string that represents a number, and you'd need one byte per character (including any leading minus sign, decimal point, or trailing decimals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference in terms of storage used whether you save a particular string in a VarChar2(100) or a VarChar2(1000) -- the length just acts as a constraint on the number of bytes (or characters) that can be stored.

The Oracle NUMBER data type does not use 4 bytes to save 1000, though. You can check the storage space by using:

```
select vsize(1000) from dual;
```

... and compare with ...

```
select vsize('1000') from dual;
```

The storage requirement for a number is more dependent on the quantity of significant figures stored, so 1000 or 1000000 require fewer bytes than 1234 or 1234567.

Answer (score 0):

If your datatype is `NUMBER(10)` then it can store max `9999999999` and min `-9999999999`

If you want to store this data to a `varchar` column then varchar(11) would be enough.